# Web Page Hight Limits?

Tags: html, css

I fully expect to be asking this question wrong, I cannot even think of phrasing that would help me, but if anybody can point me to the right direction I would be thrilled.

I am using a

`style="bottom:0;position:fixed;_position:absolute;center:0;"`

Which is what I wanted. Only if a page has to scroll, it over laps. Is there a way to only get a page to go maybe 90% of the way down and ignore the bottom 10% so that part never touches any other part of the page?

Comment: A basic front end layout would help us better understand your problem.

Comment: Please provide us with the relevant css and html.

Comment: My page is huge. I just need to know if there is a way to deligate the bottom say 10-15% of a page to not be used at all? So it ignores that and as part of the scroll down, scrolls down earlier

Comment: Adding a JS Fiddle would help us diagnose your problem.

Comment: @Zoltan Sorry, but what does "...as part of the scroll down, scrolls down earlier" mean?

Answer (score 1):

1) Why not stick your "not needed content" in a div and set its display to none? or fully remove it if you dont want to show it?

**html**

```
<div class="not-needed">
//all the stuff i dont need
</div>
```

**css**

```
.not-needed{
display:none;
}
```

2) Alternatively: place everything you need in one div and add a scroll to it, and force remove scroll from body/html.

```
<body> <!-- Remove scroll from body -->
    <div class="needed"> <!-- add scroll to this div -->
         //all the stuff i need
    </div>

    <div class="not-needed">
         //all the stuff i dont need
    </div>
</body>
```